# Xcode .embeddedframework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks

How do I use `.embeddedframework` which has resources in `xcode`? I have added in to the framework folder but during the compilation it gave me the error `Lexical or Preprocessor issue`. How do I access the header file? Do I have to adjust something in the Build setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue. When you drag the .embeddedframework into your project and when the "Choose options for adding these files" pops out, check the "Create groups for any added folders" option and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with XCode 5. I've found the solution to be simply to compile the initial program as a .framework, and then rather than storing references simply store the actual resources in another folder.  Then, for tidiness, I put all of these resources in one folder and when I added them to a project I copied them.

This worked for my particular specifications, as it wasn't in actuality that big of a deal to leave the resources exposed.